# How to print a Wordpress post's category without any markup, just plain text?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress theme and I each category in theme has a designated colour.  I want the wordpress code of simply printing out the name of the category into the id of the post so it can be set to the corresponding colour however every code I try gives html markup with it that messes up my code.  Below is how I want this to work.

```
<article> <!-- POST -->

<h1>Post title</h1>

<h2 id="***Here is where I want to insert the code to print the post's category id***>Category Name (Same code as in the ID)</h2>

<img *featured image*>

<p>blah blah article summary</p>

</article>
```

Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: is this in the category page? or on a page listing multiple posts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want this in your code...

```
 <?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->cat_name . ' '; } ?>
```

Assuming you only have one category per post, should work just fine.

Comment: How can I get the category permalink using this code? @Charlie74

Comment: I believe it is $category->term_id.

Comment: This link (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) has a list of all the return variables you can use.

Comment: Also, in the future...  it's best to ask a new question (since this one is over 4 months old), as the person you are directing the comment to may no longer be a SO user (you lucked out in this case, I still visit often).

Comment: you saved my day.

Answer (score 4):

you can use

```
<?php single_cat_title(); //prints category in plain text ?>
```

[Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_cat_title)

or

```
<?php the_category(' '); //displays category with link ?>
```

[Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category)